# Source of energy for magnetic work?

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, work

I set two magnets on my desk such that they are experiencing attraction to each other, but due to friction with the desk, are just outside of the distance where they would snap to each other. Then I expend a small amount of work to move them closer to each other, and they snap to each other. It would appear to me that the amount of work required for this motion was greater than the amount of work I did to move them closer to each other. As a result, I am guessing something not infinitely repeatable has changed about the magnets to produce energy. What has changed?

Comment: You have used up the magnetic potential energy due to the initial separation of the magnets.

Comment: Well, I didn't do any work to separate the magnets. Perhaps your answer implies that the work done was to magnetize the metal into magnets? If so, the implication is that the magnetization process stores energy in the metal. However, that implies (to me) that the magnetization of the metal is altered when the magnetic force causes work to be done (pulling the magnets toward each other).

Comment: I think what your asking is "did the magnets use up any magnetism to convert it to energy", the answer is no. The magnetic force is the thing that adds energy to the system. The whole time the magnetism is applying the same, by moving the magnets closer the force felt is increased enough to overcome the friction of the table.

Comment: "Well, I didn't do any work to separate the magnets." - Yes you did, when "I set two magnets on my desk such that...".  Assuming the magnets were initially stuck together, you did work to pull them apart and place them on the desk with some separation between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were two wires on your desk with steady currents between them then before hand there was a strong magnetic field, for instance between the two wires the fields from each added together to make a stronger field.

And magnetic fields have energy, really and truly. If you want to create a strong magnetic field you will have to do work. And if a strong magnetic field is destroyed then energy will be released. So when you have the wires on the table, that energy will be converted into kinetic energy (if you want to know the details about how, it sets up a Hall voltage from the charge imbalance made by the deflection of the moving charges in the magnetic field and then the corresponding work done by the electric field makes the wires themselves move as the magnetic field changes).

For permanent magnets, the picture for classical electrodynamics is more complicated. You need to either bring up magnetization of matter and a Gilbert or Ampere model of a magnetic dipole (a  choice of model for something, a fundamental magnetic dipole, that is truly a quantum mechanical thing) and then work it out from there. If you use the Ampere model it isn't so totally different than the example with the wire. The magnetic field between the magnets stored energy and as the magnets come together the field gets weaker and thus there is energy available. And eventually the energy that used to be in the magnetic field is converted into kinetic energy.

To be clear you can ignore the quantum effects by replacing the fundamental quantum magnetic dipole with an imaginary little super tiny loop of current (the Ampere model) that just has a given magnetic dipole moment. To describe the details of bow the permanent magnet works using classical electrodynamics you'd have to have regions where each little dipole points one way and regions where it points another way. You can describe the average of lots of dipole in a volume by an average dipole moment per unit volume and that is what we call magnetisation. It is fairly involved, but it is required to explain for instance how a a single called permanent magnet can gain or lose its magnetization. If you have it, they you can just have it. And if it isn't going to change for you, you can ignore how it changes.

But there is still a magnetic field. It still has energy and when the magnets move because of the forces on the magnets that field decreases and thus stores less energy and that's where the energy comes from and the energy goes to the kinetic energy of the magnets. But it does not do so directly, which is why you sometimes hear people say "magnetic fields do no work."

They can do work on fundamental dipoles, but you either have to use a Gilbert model and have an additional force law. Or else you need to use an Ampere model and then the magnetic forces cause an interaction with the Ampere model to cause electric fields that do the work. In advanced classes you can introduce a Lagrangian or a Hamiltonian that directly has the force of a fundamental magnetic dipole and an magnetic field. In that case it turns out the force is proportional to $\vec \nabla \left(\vec \mu \cdot \vec B\right),$ so the force depends on how the magnetic field changes, not on the magnetic field itself.

> that gets to what I am trying to understand. What is happening that recovers energy?

I think this is a separate question a out how the energy is recovered (you asked where it comes from), and I think that question might already have an answer (with more details) elsewhere on this site.

Weakening magnetic fields are accompanied with circulating electric fields. In empty space you can literally slosh the energy around where it can flow from one place to another, but it does require that there be both fields. This is why you can have electrostatics or magnetostatics as subjects but electrodynamics as a subject always means you study dynamic electric and magnetic fields.

It is the electric fields that ultimately delivers kinetic energy to charges (with an Ampere model of magnetic dipoles). So the current develops a charge imbalance from the magnetic field. The produces electric fields which give kinetic energy, but the changing charges and current decrease the energy stored in the magnetic field too. Technically the energy flows so each place where there are fields flows some energy to a nearby place and the place with the current and the electric field instead of giving on to its nearby regions gives some energy to the charges.

Comment: I can't tell: Is this tongue-in-cheek, or an honest attempt to explain something to the OP, who seems to be a beginner student? I choose to think it's the former, so *thumbs up* that's hilarious. :)

Comment: heh :) Gert's answer does not seem to have anything to do with my question. Timaeus' answer (to me, a beginner) implies that there is a change in quantum state that accounts for the energy used to move the (permanent) magnets closer together.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Edited. And I don't think it's wrong to be honest with people.

Comment: @GregJ7 While Timaeus' explaination is certainly correct, it describes a more detailed model, than is required to help you with your problem. The simple answer, that Gert tries to give you (but should maybe make clearer), is that by moving the magnets closer together, you supplied an activation energy to release a previously existing potential (magnetic potential). You can explain this without invoking quantum theory.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi The words "magnetic potential" can be confused with the vector potential and it completely sidesteps the true question of where the energy came from. Work was done to make the magnetic fields, and that energy can be recovered. Avoiding that fact is avoiding the question.

Comment: Thanks, Timaeus, that gets to what I am trying to understand. What is happening that recovers energy?

Comment: Thanks Timaeus. I have to do some reading, but I think you've addressed my question. It occurred to me that perhaps I am failing to understand magnetism as a fundamental force. If I dropped a wood block from the top of a cliff and it fell to the ground, I was, analogously, trying to understand in what way the structure of the wood block and/or the earth changed due to expended gravitational energy.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Magnets and friction]

Magnetic attraction (and repulsion) force tails off quite quickly with distance, as anyone who has manipulated magnets will know from experience. For instance, for [two point-like magnetic poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Force_between_two_magnetic_poles) the attractive force $F \propto \frac{1}{x^2}$ with $x$ the distance between the poles. So when you double the distance then the force is reduced by a factor $4$. For real magnets the relationship is more complicated but the rule of thumb holds: higher distance reduces the force.

In the diagram above are two identical magnets, exerting an attractive magnetic force $F$ on each other. The magnets also experience a friction force $F_f=\mu mg$ (in a simple model with $\mu$ the coefficient of friction). As long as friction overcomes the magnetic force, neither magnet will move.

But you moved both magnets closer together, thereby increasing $F$ and without affecting $F_f$. If at that point $F>F_f$ then the magnets will start moving together. For one magnet the equation of motion becomes:

$ma= F-F_f$ or $a=\frac{F-F_f}{m}$, and with $F>F_f \Rightarrow a>0$. Acceleration means movement.

Comment: Maybe you could help the OP even more by elaborating on how an energy is released in this process.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi: sure but 'how an energy is released' is a bit misleading a formulation. When both magnets are stationary (due to friction) they possess potential energy, much like a weight held some distance above the floor. When the magnets are brought closely together enough (to overcome friction) they start moving and the potential energy is converted to part kinetic energy, part friction work. Energy is thus conserved rather than 'released'.

Comment: As an engineer I understand that a "release" of energy is when a dormant form, such as a magnetic potential is converted to heat or mechanical work (and ultimately heat again).